# How can I rewrite this multiple OR condition so that it uses a Perl "for" loop?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, loops, for-loop

I have a hard-coded if loops that looks like this:

```
my $tp = 0;
my $fp = 0;
if (   $myhash{$pred}
        || $myhash{$pred1}
        || $myhash{$pred2}
        || $myhash{$pred3}
        || $myhash{$pred4}
        || $myhash{$pred5}
        || $myhash{$pred6} )
    {
        $tp++;
    }
    else {
        $fp++;
    }
```

How can I do that in for loops?

I tried the following but it give different result in total of `fp` and `tp`:

```
my $tp=0;
my $fp=0;

my @allpreds = ($pred,$pred1,$pred2,$pred3,$pred4,$pred5);

foreach my $allpred ( @allpreds ) {
        if ( $myhash{$allpred} ) {
            $tp++;

        }

    }
if ( !myhash{$pred} ) {
        $fp++;
    }
```

Comment: an if() is NOT A LOOP. Also, there are 7 predicates in the first code block, and only 6 predicates in the second code block.

Comment: Hm, shouldn’t that be `$fn++` not `$fp++`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $tp=0;
my $fp=0;
my $count=0;

my @allpreds = ($pred,$pred1,$pred2,$pred3,$pred4,$pred5);

foreach my $allpred ( @allpreds ) {
        if ( $myhash{$allpred} ) {
            $count++;

        }

    }

if ($count>0) { $tp=1; } else { $fp=1; }
```

Comment: The original code will short circuit when it finds the first true predicate. The loop in this answer won't. If profiling shows this to be a problem (e.g.: LOTS of predicates or an expensively tied %myhash) you can make the loop short circuit by replacing "$count++;" with "$tp++; last;" and changing the last line to "$fp++ unless $tp;"

Comment: @benrifkah Good points. Adding "count" hopefully let him see why his first two attempts produce different outcomes.

Comment: You can also just add "last if ($count>0);" inside the foreach/if if you want to speed things up a bit

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat more compact than some answers, but fully equivalent.

```
my $tp = 0;
my $fp = 0;

foreach my $allpred ($pred, $pred1, $pred2, $pred3, $pred4, $pred5)
{
    $tp++, last if ($myhash{$allpred});
}

$fp = !$tp;
```

It is not clear that the variable `$fp` earns its keep when `!$tp` is almost as simple to write.

---

Test code - change the settings on the RHS of the fat commas to change the behaviour of the test.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pred   = "";
my $pred1  = "1";
my $pred2  = "2 2";
my $pred3  = "3 3 3";
my $pred4  = "4 4 4 4";
my $pred5  = "5 5 5 5 5";
my %myhash = ( $pred1 => 0, $pred2 => 0, $pred3 => 0, $pred4 => 0, $pred5 => 1 );

my $tp = 0;
my $fp = 0;

foreach my $allpred ($pred, $pred1, $pred2, $pred3, $pred4, $pred5)
{
    $tp++, last if ($myhash{$allpred});
}

$fp = !$tp;

printf "%d:%d\n", $tp, $fp;
```

Comment: @Paul: why won't $tp equal what it does in the OP's first example?  If it is because the first example includes $pred6 and the second doesn't, then yes, I suppose by the letter you are correct.  Of course, having the predicates in N separate variables instead of an array is not entirely sensible.

Comment: Oops... you are correct - looks like I misread the comma statement.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` will return a true value when any one or more of its inputs returns true for it's statement, basically allowing it to act like a chain of `||`'ed statements, except that it won't short circuit.

```
my @allpreds = ($pred, $pred1, $pred2, $pred3, $pred4, $pred5, $pred6);
if (grep { $myhash{$_} } @allpreds) {
    $tp++;
}
else {
    $fp++;
}
```

Using `grep` this way can be a bit confusing so a more explicit way is to use [List::MoreUtils `any`](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aMoreUtils#any)

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);
my @allpreds = ($pred, $pred1, $pred2, $pred3, $pred4, $pred5, $pred6);
if (any { $myhash{$_} } @allpreds) {
    $tp++;
}
else {
    $fp++;
}
```